# Calling different child class function from the same parent invocation

Tags: c++

Consider this trivial C++11 inheritance example:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void func() { func1(); /* Wish this could be func1() or func2()! */ };

    void func1() { /* Does one thing */ };
    void func2() { /* Does another thing */ };
};

void doSomeStuff(A &a) 
{
    a.func();
}

int main()
{
    B b;

    doSomeStuff(b);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that I don't have to modify (or duplicate) class A's definition or the function doSomeStuff, but I want the invocation of a.func() to call either func1() or func2() of B.  Ideally I'd change the line `doSomeStuff(b)` to something like `doSomeStuff(b.butWithFunc1)` but I'd also be OK with some way to modify B's version of `func()` so that it can make the decision internally to call `func1` or `func2` based on some parameter.

The same object of type B may have to sometimes call `func1` or `func2` during an invocation of `func`, so I can't use a persistent member of class B to decide.  Adding a parameter to func() would make this trivial as well, but that's not something I can do either.

I'm kind of wondering if there's some way to add to class B a function that returns a mutated version of class B which calls func2() from func(), or if I can play some tricks with function pointers or something.  However, something tells me I'm Doing It Wrong and the obvious solution is staring me in the face.

If it helps for context, class A is similar to a std::lock_guard, and it works fine for things like semaphores and mutexes (for which there is only one definition of lock and unlock), but class B in this example is a R/W lock - so there's a "readLock" and "writeLock", and I'd like to be able to say something like "auto lock this RW lock as a read lock" without having to duplicate/break the auto lock code.

For instance:

```
{
    A_AutoSem(myMutex); // calls lock() on myMutex
    //... do some stuff

    // end of the block, ~A_AutoSem calls unlock on myMutex
}

{
    A_AutoSem(B_RWLock); // how do I say here "call readLock"?
    // ... do some stuff

    // end of the block ~A_AutoSem should call "readUnlock" on B_RWLock
}
```

Comment: That's very vague. Neither `func1` nor `func2` do anything, and it's not clear why you can't use a member of B.

Comment: What kind of logic dictates the "sometimes" portion of choosing between `func1()` and `func2()`? I'm not really getting why a simple conditional and a member value to track some state wouldn't work.

Comment: @melpomene, perhaps considering the RW lock as the context will help there.  I can't use a member of B because there might be 2 threads using B and one wants to lock as read and the other as write at the same time.

Comment: Why would those threads be using the same code to do so?

Comment: I added a more concrete instance of an example, maybe that will help with understanding the constraints.

Comment: How are `A_AutoSem`, `myMutex`, and `B_RWLock` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply define some additional classes to call `func1()` and `func2()`, and then pass those classes to `doSomeStuff()` instead of passing `B` directly.

Try something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    void func1() { /* Does one thing */ };
    void func2() { /* Does another thing */ };
};

class C1 : public A
{
private:
    B &m_b;
public:
    C1(B &b) : m_b(b) {}
    void func() override { m_b.func1(); }
};

class C2 : public A
{
private:
    B &m_b;
public:
    C2(B &b) : m_b(b) {}
    void func() override { m_b.func2(); }
};

void doSomeStuff(A &a) 
{
    a.func();
}

int main()
{
    B b;

    {
    C1 c(b);
    doSomeStuff(c);
    }

    {
    C2 c(b);
    doSomeStuff(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/G3RjoM)

Alternatively:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class B
{
private:
    void func1() { /* Does one thing */ };
    void func2() { /* Does another thing */ };

public:
    class C1 : public A
    {
    private:
        B &m_b;
    public:
        C1(B &b) : m_b(b) {}
        void func() override { m_b.func1(); }
    };

    class C2 : public A
    {
    private:
        B &m_b;
    public:
        C2(B &b) : m_b(b) {}
        void func() override { m_b.func2(); }
    };
};

void doSomeStuff(A &a) 
{
    a.func();
}

int main()
{
    B b;

    {
    B::C1 c(b);
    doSomeStuff(c);
    }

    {
    B::C2 c(b);
    doSomeStuff(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Y2qc7c)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, _Curious_: I wonder if this can also do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913754/c-member-function-pointer-with-different-arguments-or-is-this-bad-anyway/42253857#42253857

Comment: @MohammadKanan: "*I'm trying to make it so that I don't have to modify (or duplicate) class A's definition or the function doSomeStuff*".  Specifying which method to call would require modifying `doSomeStuff`, which the OP does not want.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Seeing your solution makes me realize that the problem is my B class isn't really a child of A - your C's are really the child classes of A, and adapt B to fit its model.  Thank you for your help!